# Replacing macOS with elementary OS. Computer boots normally into elementary OS, but boot menu (option key on boot) doesn't show anything

Tags: mac, startup, efi

I want to replace macOS with elementary OS on a Mac.

I formated the entire hard disk, inserted the elementary OS bootable USB, selected EFI boot on the boot loader (only option) and installed elementary OS. Everything works well.

The computer boots normally into elementary OS, but if I press the <kbd>option</kbd> key on boot, nothing shows on the bootloader.

If I install, choose something else and create just the root and swap partition i get a Windows partion on the boot loader. This leads me to think that is something related to installing in the EFI mode.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Also, why when I insert the live USB, I only get the EFI option and not the windows (bios mode) option when I press the <kbd>option</kbd> key?

Edit:

The first method provided by David Anderson worked.

I just want to add that i made a systemd service to clone the grubx64.efi on every reboot/shutdown so that even if this file gets updated, BOOTx64.EFI are updated as well. This will also automate the solution given by David.

This is what i did:

1 - Create a file named startup-manager-fix.service with the following text:

```
[Unit]
Description=Show EFI Install in Apple Startup Manager
After=rc-local.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=-/bin/mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/
ExecStop=/bin/cp -a -f /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2 - Copy the above file to the folder /etc/systemd/system/

3 - Open the terminal and insert this command to activate the service that will sync both files.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl enable startup-manager-fix.service && sudo systemctl start startup-manager-fix.service && sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

4 - reboot and the next time you access the apple boot selector (press the option key on startup) the elementary OS ( or other Ubuntu based distro) EFI Installation should be present.

Thanks again to David for the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note: In the examples below, the download elementary OS installation was named `elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20180214.iso`. The images were created using VirtualBox 5.2.16 r123759 (Qt5.6.3).

### Why does nothing appear in the Startup Manager when installing for an EFI boot?

As you have discovered, Macs can be configured to boot operating systems that do not always appear in the Startup Manager. This can be corrected. Let us start with normal EFI booting install of the elementary OS. Right click on the icon labeled `Files` in the `Applications` menu, then select `New Windows as Administrator`, as shown below.

[image: j1]

Under `Devices`, click on `File System`. You should get a window similar to what is shown below.

[image: j2]

Next, open the the following folders: `boot`, `efi`, `EFI` and finally `ubuntu`. You should get a window similar to what is shown below.

[image: j3]

When your Mac boots, the software stored in the `grubx64.efi` file is executed. Unfortunately, this file has a name and is stored in a folder that will not be recognized by the Startup Manager. Therefore, noting appears when you hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> at startup. One simple solution would be to

1. Create a `BOOT` folder in the `EFI` folder.
2. Copy from the `grubx64.efi` file from the `ubuntu` folder to the `BOOT` folder.
3. Rename the `grubx64.efi` file in the `BOOT` folder to `BOOTx64.EFI`.

The image below shows the contents of the `BOOT` folder after having followed the above steps.

[image: j4]

Finally, follow the steps given below to insure the Mac boot loader executes the `BOOTx64.EFI` file.

1. Restart your Mac and immediately press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key on your keyboard.
2. Release the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you see the Startup Manager window.
3. Hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting the internal disk icon labeled `EFI boot`

The elementary OS will now appear in the Startup Manager as an internal drive icon with the label `EFI boot`.

The above solution has one problem: **The elementary OS has no idea you made these changes**. Therefore, any updates to the `grubx64.efi` file will not be automatically copied to the `BOOTx64.EFI` file. A better solution, that avoids this problem, is given below.

First, use the `Epiphany` Web Browser to download the [rEFInd Boot Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). In my case, the file `refind_0.11.3-1_amd64.deb` was downloaded to my `Downloads` folder. When finished, quit the `Epiphany` application.

Next, right click on the icon labeled `Terminal` in the `Applications` menu, then select `New Window`. You should get a window similar to what is shown below.

[image: j6]

In the `Terminal` window, enter the following commands. If you downloaded a different file or downloaded to a different folder, then make the appropriate substitutions. When finished, quit the `Terminal` application.

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i refind_0.11.3-1_amd64.deb
```

The result, of running the above commands, was the creation of the `refind` and `tools` folders in the `EFI` folder, as shown below.

[image: j5]

Next, you will need to make the following modifications.

1. If the `BOOT` folder does not exist, then create this folder. Otherwise, remove the contents of this folder.
2. Copy the contents from the `refind` folder to the `BOOT` folder.
3. Rename the `refind_x64.efi` file in the `BOOT` folder to `BOOTx64.EFI`.
4. Right click on the `refind.conf` file in the `BOOT` folder and then select `Open in Scratch`.
5. Add the following lines at the end of the opened `refind.conf` file.

   ```
   #
   # Added to make rEFInd silent. 
   #
   menuentry "Elementary" {
       icon \EFI\BOOT\icons\os_elementary.png
       volume "EFI"
       loader \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
       ostype Linux
       graphics on
   }
   timeout -1
   hideui all
   scanfor manual
   ```
6. Close the `refind.conf` tab and quit the `Scratch` application.

Finally, follow the steps given below to insure the Mac boot loader executes the `BOOTx64.EFI` file.

1. Restart your Mac and immediately press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key on your keyboard.
2. Release the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you see the Startup Manager window.
3. Hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while selecting the internal disk icon labeled `EFI boot`

Now, when you select the internal disk icon labeled `EFI boot` in the Startup Manager, rEFInd will silently boot elementary OS.

### Why does an icon with the `Windows` label appear in the Startup Manager when installing for an BIOS boot?

Orignially, when Apple first allowed Windows to be installed on Macs, Windows had to be installed for a BIOS boot. Therefore, Apple used `Windows` as the label displayed in the Boot Manager when any BIOS booting operating system was installed. This convention was repeated in all Macs until 2015, when Apple started shipping Macs that could no longer BIOS boot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will try it and i tell you how it went. "The above solution has one problem: The elementary OS has no idea you made these changes. Therefore, any updates to the grubx64.efi file will not be automatically copied to the bootx64.efi file. A better solution, that avoids this problem, is given below." What if i put this on the rc.local executable? Would't it update every time i boot the computer? Do you know why i don't see the bios installation option on the bootloader when i insert the live usb? Thanks again.

Comment: The `grubx64.efi` and `BOOTx64.EFI` files execute before the `rc.local` file. If an update changed `grubx64.efi` in a way that would require `grubx64.efi` to be copied to `BOOTX64.EFI`, the copy operation stored in `rc.local` would not execute before`BOOTX64.EFI` executes. Basically, `grubx64.efi` and `BOOTx64.EFI` are GRUB files, where as `rc.local` is a linux file. GRUB executes before linux.

Comment: The Mac firmware can not BIOS boot from a USB port. The firmware in certain Mac models can BIOS boot from an optical drive or from an internal drive. One workaround would be to BIOS boot a USB drive from VirtualBox and install to an internal physical drive. This method should only be employed by experienced Mac users. Also, in practice, one would use an ISO file instead of a USB drive.

Comment: Another problem with using `rc.local` would be if an update or upgrade of elementary OS changed, replaced or removed the `rc.local` file. In such a case, the copy operation could be eliminated. The rEFInd Boot Manager eliminates this problem. The rEFInd Boot Manager does  not actually boot load anything. What happens is that rEFInd tells the Mac boot loader the correct files to boot load. When your Mac starts up, the Mac boot loader boots rEFInd. Next, rEFInd instructs the Mac boot loader to boot GRUB. The Mac restarts and the Mac boot loader boots GRUB. Finally, GRUB boots elementary OS.

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed explanation. Is there a problem if the grubx64.efi and BOOTx64.EFI contents don't match? Isn't the BOOTx64.EFI just for showing the "efi boot" disk in the apple bootloader? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I do not undestand your question regarding "Is there a problem if the grubx64.efi and BOOTx64.EFI contents don't match?". The detection of the `BOOTX64.EFI` file by the Mac boot loader is just the way Apple decided to fulfill the requirements on page 91 of the [UEFI specification](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202_7_A%20Sept%206.pdf).

Comment: Hi. If i make rc.local copy grubx64.efi to BOOTX64.EFI on every boot and Elementary updates grubx64.efi, on the next reboot this two files will not have the some content until the computer finishes booting (rc.local is executed), but if BOOTX64.EFI is just needed for the drive to appear on the bootloader, it won't matter since the computer will boot anyways and when it finishes i will have both equal again. Unrelated question: The BOOTX64.EFI file is suppose to be all in capital letter, right? Not BOOTx64.EFI or bootx64.efi? Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I changed my answer to insure `BOOTx64.EFI` is executed instead of `grubx64.efi`. The UEFI specification uses the spelling `BOOTx64.EFI`, but I believe the Mac boot loader is case independent with respect to file names.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not understanding i right, but since the bootloader will always load Elementary through the BOOTx64.EFI file (after control+enter), what happens if this file is outdated (before rc.local makes it equal with grubx64.efi)? The computer will not boot? Thank for you patience.

Comment: In theory, the computer may not boot after an update. This is why using rEFInd may be a better solution. Other solutions also exist. For example, you could also boot to macOS Recovery or an external drive and bless the `grubx64.efi` file each time the Mac fails to boot properly.

Comment: By blessing you mean return to the state that was before using ctrl+enter (BOOTx64.EFI) on the bootloader, right? Mounting the hard disk and manualy copying the file with a elementary liveusb would accomplish the same? What if i run a script on every shutodown/reboot (systemd service)? This way grub64.efi and BOOTx64.EFI will always be in sync even after an update and i will not have the rc.local problem, right? Thanks.

Comment: I mean ignore my answer entirely. You can set the file that the Mac boot loader executes by using the [`bless`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/bless/) command. Since elementary OS is the only operating system installed on your Mac, you would need to enter this command by booting to either [Internet macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904), a [macOS USB flash drive installer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) or macOS installed on an external drive. You would use the `bless` command to set `grubx64.efi` as the default file for the Mac boot loader to execute at startup.

Comment: BTW, what is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: 2008 macbook. Do you think that running an executable that sync both files on every shutdown/reboot could work? What about a nvram reset? What file does the bootloader choose after the reset. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It seems that it's working. Thank you very much for your patience.